# ReactCSSTransitionGroup: Keep appear/appearActive classes after transition?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

everyone!  I'm working with ReactCSSTransitionGroup elements, and I'm using the new (well, relatively) `appear` class to get an element to fade in on render.  I was just wondering if it's possible to tell React to preserve transition classes *after* transition.  For example:

```
// jsx
render() {
  return (
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName={ {
        appear: 'ready'
      } }
      transitionAppear={true}
    >
      <div class="whatever">Whatever!</div>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
 );
```

}

```
// css
.whatever {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.whatever.ready {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I'd like the `ready` modifier class to stay on the `.whatever` div if possible.  I know that this is opposite of the expected behavior of ReactCSSTransitionGroup components, but in this situation, I can't change the CSS to reverse the "fade in" animation states (which I know would be much easier).  But I feel as though it wouldn't be out of the realm of possibility if there were an option to preserve transition classes after the actual transition.  (I could pass in `transitionAppearTimeout={Infinity}` to simulate what I want, but that's not great for obvious reasons!)

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you create another class with `opacity: 1`, and you add that class to the div that is added to the DOM, this class it will obviously remain.

If you make sure this class is less specific than the `whatever` classes it will remain after the transition.